# AngularJS 1.5+ Components do not support Watchers, what is the work around?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-components, angularjs-1.5

I've been upgrading my custom directives to the new [component architecture](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component#component-based-application-architecture). I've read that components do not support watchers. Is this correct? If so how do you detect changes on an object? For a basic example I have custom component `myBox` which has a child component game with a binding on the game . If  there is a change game within the game component how do I show an alert message within the myBox? I understand there is rxJS method is it possible to do this purely in angular? My [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bkarv/swv22g3s/)

**JavaScript**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {

   $scope.name = "Tony Danza";

});

app.component("myBox",  {
      bindings: {},
      controller: function($element) {
        var myBox = this;
        myBox.game = 'World Of warcraft';
        //IF myBox.game changes, show alert message 'NAME CHANGE'
      },
      controllerAs: 'myBox',
      templateUrl: "/template",
      transclude: true
})
app.component("game",  {
      bindings: {game:'='},
      controller: function($element) {
        var game = this;


      },
      controllerAs: 'game',
      templateUrl: "/template2"
})
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="mainCtrl">
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="/template">
    <div style='width:40%;border:2px solid black;background-color:yellow'>
      Your Favourite game is: {{myBox.game}}
      <game game='myBox.game'></game>
    </div>
  </script>

 <script type="text/ng-template" id="/template2">
    <div>
    </br>
        Change Game
      <textarea ng-model='game.game'></textarea>
    </div>
  </script>

  Hi {{name}}
  <my-box>

  </my-box>

</div><!--end app-->
```

Answer (score 160, accepted):

### Writing Components without [Watchers](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch)

This answer outlines five techniques to use to write AngularJS 1.5 components without using [watchers.](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch)

- Use the [`ng-change` Directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange)
- Use the [`$onChanges` Life-cycle Hook](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#life-cycle-hooks)
- Use the [`$doCheck` Life-cycle Hook](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#life-cycle-hooks)
- Intercomponent Communication with [require](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-require-)
- Push Values from a Service with [RxJS](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/rx.angular.js)

---

### Use the `ng-change` Directive

> what alt methods available to observe obj state changes without using watch in preparation for AngularJs2?

You can use the `ng-change` directive to react to input changes.

```
<textarea ng-model='game.game' 
          ng-change="game.textChange(game.game)">
</textarea>
```

And to propagate the event to a parent component, the event handler needs to be added as an attribute of the child component.

```
<game game='myBox.game' game-change='myBox.gameChange($value)'></game>
```

JS

```
app.component("game",  {
      bindings: {game:'=',
                 gameChange: '&'},
      controller: function() {
        var game = this;
        game.textChange = function (value) {
            game.gameChange({$value: value});
        });

      },
      controllerAs: 'game',
      templateUrl: "/template2"
});
```

And in the parent component:

```
myBox.gameChange = function(newValue) {
    console.log(newValue);
});
```

This is the preferred method going forward. The AngularJS strategy of using `$watch` is not scalable because it is a polling strategy. When the number of `$watch` listeners reaches around 2000, the UI gets sluggish. The strategy in Angular 2 is to make the framework more reactive and avoid placing `$watch` on `$scope`.

---

### Use the `$onChanges` Life-cycle Hook

With **version 1.5.3**, AngularJS added the `$onChanges` life-cycle hook to the `$compile` service.

From the Docs:

> The controller can provide the following methods that act as life-cycle hooks:
>
> - $onChanges(changesObj) - Called whenever one-way (`<`) or interpolation (`@`) bindings are updated. The `changesObj` is a hash whose keys are the names of the bound properties that have changed, and the values are an object of the form `{ currentValue: ..., previousValue: ... }`. Use this hook to trigger updates within a component such as cloning the bound value to prevent accidental mutation of the outer value.
>
> [— AngularJS Comprehensive Directive API Reference -- Life-cycle hooks](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#life-cycle-hooks)

The `$onChanges` hook is used to react to external changes into the component with `<` one-way bindings. The `ng-change` directive is used to propogate changes from the `ng-model` controller outside the component with `&` bindings.

---

### Use the `$doCheck` Life-cycle Hook

With **version 1.5.8**, AngularJS added the `$doCheck` life-cycle hook to the `$compile` service.

From the Docs:

> The controller can provide the following methods that act as life-cycle hooks:
>
> - `$doCheck()` - Called on each turn of the digest cycle. Provides an opportunity to detect and act on changes. Any actions that you wish to take in response to the changes that you detect must be invoked from this hook; implementing this has no effect on when `$onChanges` is called. For example, this hook could be useful if you wish to perform a deep equality check, or to check a Date object, changes to which would not be detected by Angular's change detector and thus not trigger `$onChanges`. This hook is invoked with no arguments; if detecting changes, you must store the previous value(s) for comparison to the current values.
>
> [— AngularJS Comprehensive Directive API Reference -- Life-cycle hooks](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#life-cycle-hooks)

---

## Intercomponent Communication with `require`

Directives can [require](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-require-) the controllers of other directives to enable communication between each other. This can be achieved in a component by providing an object mapping for the [require](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-require-) property. The object keys specify the property names under which the required controllers (object values) will be bound to the requiring component's controller.

```
app.component('myPane', {
  transclude: true,
  require: {
    tabsCtrl: '^myTabs'
  },
  bindings: {
    title: '@'
  },
  controller: function() {
    this.$onInit = function() {
      this.tabsCtrl.addPane(this);
      console.log(this);
    };
  },
  templateUrl: 'my-pane.html'
});
```

For more information, see [AngularJS Developer Guide - Intercomponent Communicatation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component#intercomponent-communication)

---

## Push Values from a Service with [RxJS](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/rx.angular.js)

> What about in a situation where you have a Service that's holding state for example. How could I push changes to that Service, and other random components on the page be aware of such a change? Been struggling with tackling this problem lately

Build a service with [RxJS Extensions for Angular](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/rx.angular.js).

```
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/rx/dist/rx.all.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/rx-angular/dist/rx.angular.js"></script>
```

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['rx']);

app.factory("DataService", function(rx) {
  var subject = new rx.Subject(); 
  var data = "Initial";

  return {
      set: function set(d){
        data = d;
        subject.onNext(d);
      },
      get: function get() {
        return data;
      },
      subscribe: function (o) {
         return subject.subscribe(o);
      }
  };
});
```

Then simply subscribe to the changes.

```
app.controller('displayCtrl', function(DataService) {
  var $ctrl = this;

  $ctrl.data = DataService.get();
  var subscription = DataService.subscribe(function onNext(d) {
      $ctrl.data = d;
  });

  this.$onDestroy = function() {
      subscription.dispose();
  };
});
```

Clients can subscribe to changes with `DataService.subscribe` and producers can push changes with `DataService.set`.

The [DEMO on PLNKR](https://plnkr.co/edit/YVKGhCx0DrzyzckMDjtv?p=preview).

Comment: Thanks I'm looking to react to the change of myBox.game rather than game.gameChange. As this is not an input but label, the above may not work. I think I may have to resort to rxjs in the end...

Comment: I added info for propogating events to parent components.

Comment: how this thing will handle up programmatic value change on `myBox.game` variable?

Comment: Great answer @georgeawg. What about in a situation where you have a `Service` that's holding state for example. How could I push changes to that Service, and other random components on the page be aware of such a change? Been struggling with tackling this problem lately...

Comment: @MarkPieszak You have a good question. Ask it with a specific example and see what answers you get.

Comment: @KaTech @georgeawg try to avoid bindings with `=`. To avoid mutation of the parent scope is a better practice to use `>` and clone it every time it changes using the `$onChanges` method. via: [Official docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component#component-based-application-architecture)

Comment: @MarkPieszak See updated answer with example of a reactive service.

Comment: Good answer, only say that you can improve your RxJS solution using rx.BehaviorSubject() instead of rx.Subject(), which do the job of storing the last value by itself,  and can be initialized with a default value just like you did in your service

Answer (score 8):

<strike>`$watch` object is available inside `$scope` object, so you need to add `$scope` inside your controller factory function & then place watcher over the variable.</strike>

```
$scope.$watch(function(){
    return myBox.game;
}, function(newVal){
   alert('Value changed to '+ newVal)
});
```

[**Demo Here**](https://jsfiddle.net/swv22g3s/11/)

> **Note:** I know you had converted `directive` to `component`, to remove dependency of `$scope` so that you will get one step closer to
>   Angular2. But it seems like it didn't get removed for this case.

**Update**

Basically angular 1.5 does added `.component` method jus differentiate two different functionality. Like `component`.stands to perform particular behaviby adding `selector`, where as `directive` stands to add specific behavior to DOM. Directive is just wrapper method on `.directive` DDO(Directive Definition Object). Only what you can see is, they had remove `link/compile` function while using `.component` method where you had an ability to get angular compiled DOM.

Do use `$onChanges`/`$doCheck` lifecycle hook of Angular component lifecycle hook, those will be available after Angular 1.5.3+ version.

> **$onChanges(changesObj)** - Called whenever bindings are updated. The changesObj is a hash whose keys are the names of the bound properties.
>
> **$doCheck()** - Called on each turn of the digest cycle when binding changes. Provides an opportunity to detect and act on changes.

By using same function inside component will ensure your code to be compatible to move to Angular 2.

Comment: Thanks for this, I guess will have stick to this now. Are you able to point me to any links that discuss what alt methods available to observe obj state changes without using watch in preparation for AngularJs2?

Comment: @KaTech now I can only say use `observable` of `RxJS`, that would be good compatible with `Angular2`

Answer (score 4):

To anyone interested in my solution, I end up resorting to RXJS Observables, which what you will have to use when you get to Angular 2. Here is a working fiddle for communications between components, it gives me more control on what to watch.

[JS FIDDLE RXJS Observables](https://jsfiddle.net/0maek0qr/)

```
class BoxCtrl {
    constructor(msgService) {
    this.msgService = msgService
    this.msg = ''

    this.subscription = msgService.subscribe((obj) => {
      console.log('Subscribed')
      this.msg = obj
    })
    }

  unsubscribe() {
    console.log('Unsubscribed')
    msgService.usubscribe(this.subscription)
  }
}

var app = angular
  .module('app', ['ngMaterial'])
  .controller('MainCtrl', ($scope, msgService) => {
    $scope.name = "Observer App Example";
    $scope.msg = 'Message';
    $scope.broadcast = function() {
      msgService.broadcast($scope.msg);
    }
  })
  .component("box", {
    bindings: {},
    controller: 'BoxCtrl',
    template: `Listener: </br>
    <strong>{{$ctrl.msg}}</strong></br>
    <md-button ng-click='$ctrl.unsubscribe()' class='md-warn'>Unsubscribe A</md-button>`
  })
  .factory('msgService', ['$http', function($http) {
    var subject$ = new Rx.ReplaySubject();
    return {
      subscribe: function(subscription) {
        return subject$.subscribe(subscription);
      },
      usubscribe: function(subscription) {
        subscription.dispose();
      },
      broadcast: function(msg) {
        console.log('success');
        subject$.onNext(msg);
      }
    }
  }])
```

Answer (score 2):

A small heads-up regarding the use of `ng-change`, as recommended with the accepted answer, together with an angular 1.5 component.

In case you need to watch a component that `ng-model` and `ng-change` do not work, you can pass the parameters as:

Markup in which component is used:

```
<my-component on-change="$ctrl.doSth()"
              field-value="$ctrl.valueToWatch">
</my-component>
```

Component js:

```
angular
  .module('myComponent')
  .component('myComponent', {
    bindings: {
      onChange: '&',
      fieldValue: '='
    }
  });
```

Component markup:

```
<select ng-model="$ctrl.fieldValue"
        ng-change="$ctrl.onChange()">
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Available in IE11, MutationObserver https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver. You need to inject $element service into controller which semi-breaks DOM/controller separation, but I feel that this is a fundamental exception (ie. flaw) in angularjs. Since hide/show is async, we need on-show callback, that angularjs & angular-bootstrap-tab do not provide. It also requires that u know which specific DOM element u want to observe. I used following code for angularjs controller to trigger Highcharts chart reflow on-show.

```
const myObserver = new MutationObserver(function (mutations) {
    const isVisible = $element.is(':visible') // Requires jquery
    if (!_.isEqual(isVisible, $element._prevIsVisible)) { // Lodash
        if (isVisible) {
            $scope.$broadcast('onReflowChart')
        }
        $element._prevIsVisible = isVisible
    }
})
myObserver.observe($element[0], {
    attributes: true,
    attributeFilter: ['class']
})
```

Comment: To make the migration to Angular2+ easier, avoid using `$scope` and `$rootScope`. Consider using [RxJS](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/rx.angular.js) instead for event emitters and subscribers.

Answer (score 0):

Really Nice accepted answer, but I might add that you can use also the power of events ( a bit like in Qt signal / slots if you will ).

An event is broadcast : `$rootScope.$broadcast("clickRow", rowId)`
by any parent ( or even children controller ).
Then in your controller you can handle the event like this :

```
$scope.$on("clickRow", function(event, data){
    // do a refresh of the view with data == rowId
});
```

You can also add some logging on that like this ( taken from here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/34903433/3147071 )

```
var withLogEvent = true; // set to false to avoid events logs
app.config(function($provide) {
    if (withLogEvent)
    {
      $provide.decorator("$rootScope", function($delegate) {
        var Scope = $delegate.constructor;
        var origBroadcast = Scope.prototype.$broadcast;
        var origEmit = Scope.prototype.$emit;

        Scope.prototype.$broadcast = function() {
          console.log("$broadcast was called on $scope " + this.$id + " with arguments:",
                     arguments);
          return origBroadcast.apply(this, arguments);
        };
        Scope.prototype.$emit = function() {
          console.log("$emit was called on $scope " + this.$id + " with arguments:",
                     arguments);
          return origEmit.apply(this, arguments);
        };
        return $delegate;
      });
    }
});
```

Comment: With Angular 2+ the event bus is going away (event busses have performance issues.) To make the migration to Angular2+ easier, avoid using `$scope` and `$rootScope`. Consider using [RxJS](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/rx.angular.js) instead for event emitters and subscribers.

Answer (score 0):

I'm late. But it can help to another people.

```
app.component("headerComponent", {
    templateUrl: "templates/header/view.html",
    controller: ["$rootScope", function ($rootScope) {
        let $ctrl = this;
        $rootScope.$watch(() => {
            return $ctrl.val;
        }, function (newVal, oldVal) {
            // do something
        });
    }]
});
```

Comment: can you explain why this works? Isn't abusing rootscope a bad idea?