# Watching for changes to all view models in a form

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-model

I would like to execute a function any time that values in a form (or accompanying model) are changed in AngularJS 1.6. I've tried a few things, including `$scope.$watch`, but it seems this method isn't available in 1.6.

Other than putting an `ng-change` attribute on each form element, what can I do? Tried putting this on the form too, but AngularJS complains that there is no `ng-model`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35534479/angularjs-1-5-component-does-not-support-watchers-what-is-the-work-around

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use object notations in your ng-model please refer the following code and plunker link. It may help you.

in your html:

```
    <form name="details">
    <div>
      <input type="text" ng-model="formDetails.firstName" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="text" ng-model="formDetails.secondName" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <button ng-click="fnSubmit()">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </form>
```

in your controller:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.formDetails={}
  $scope.fnSubmit=function(){
    console.log($scope.formDetails);
  }
});
```

What ever may be the version it will work fine. We can avoid using ng-change for each input field in your form.

Please find the [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/vR8nXZOPn38i90WZeTvM?p=preview) link

Answer (score 0):

I could think of creating a custom directive for this:

```
yourModule.directive("formChanged", function ($parse) {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

        var handler = $parse(attrs.formChanged);

        element.find('[ng-model]').each(function () {
            $(this).on('change', function () {
                handler(scope)();
            });
        });
    }
  }
});
```

Then you can use this on your form or any other HTML element like this:

```
<form form-changed="yourChangeCallback">
   <input type="text" ng-model="model.example"/>
</form>
```

Now the directive actually will just set an `onchange` event on every element that has the `ngModel` directive.

Comment: Pretty elegant, but I can imagine that not always the `ng-model` is attached to input fields, for example with custom directives/3rd party directives. I think you can just bind the `change` event to the form instead

Comment: Well, I did not think of that case but actually I never used a 3rd party that added the `ngModel` directive itself. However, the whole solution is a pretty static approach and requires all the input elements to be already there when evaluated. The directive still could be improved.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a directive that listens to some events of the form:

```
.directive("formOnChange", function($parse){
    return {
        require: "form",
        link: function(scope, element, attrs){
            var cb = $parse(attrs.formOnChange);
            element.on("change keyup", function(){
                cb(scope);
            });
        }
    }
});
```

And usage:

```
<form name="myForm"
      form-on-change="doSomething()">
```

Answer (score 0):

One idea is to create an `ng-model` directive that reports changes to a service.

```
app.directive("ngModel", function(changeService) {
    return {
        require: "ngModel",
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ngModel) {
            ngModel.$viewChangeListeners.push(
                function () {
                    changeService.report(ngModel.$viewValue, elem, attrs);
                } 
            );
        })
    };
});
```

The above example adds a [$viewChangeListener](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#$viewChangeListeners) to each [ngModelController](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController) which reports changes to a service. The [$viewChangeListeners](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#$viewChangeListeners) array is the same hook that the `ng-change` directive uses.

Example of a service:

```
app.service("changeService", function() {
    this.report = function(value, elem, attrs) {
        var name = attrs.name || attrs.ngModel; 
        console.log(name + " changed to " + value);
    };
});
```

The [DEMO in PLNKR.](https://plnkr.co/edit/7C1tPYiifRHCHoxeMwqa?p=preview)