# Angular 1.6 ES6 $watch

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ecmascript-6, angularjs-1.6

**Edit/ update :**

I forgot my original code in angular 1.6 (normal way)  :

http://codepen.io/darkiron/pen/qRJmaj

I think, this can helpe you. 
My job is convert in EcmaScript ES6.

---

who work great !

How to use `$watch` in ES6 Angular controller ?

```
  loginaction(){

    this.$scope.$watch('ui.shake', this.resetUiCheck());
    ....
 }
```

I try this, the result is not expected

```
resetUiCheck(newValue, oldValue){    
    console.log(this.ui.shake);
    return () => {
        alert('foo');
        console.log(this);
        if(this.ui.shake == true){
            this.$timeout(function(){
                this.ui.shake = false;
            }, 1000);
        }
    };

}
```

return always false!

I try this:

```
this.$scope.$watch('ui.shake', this.resetUiCheck);
```

And the result is this error

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'ui' of undefined

Another question: the `$watch` function should not be set in the Contoller constructor?

Comment: 1. Why `$watch` at all? 2. Why `$timeout`? 3. What do you mean by _"return always false"_?

Comment: Read [How to Debug Small Programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: See also [AngularJs 1.5 - Component does not support Watchers, what is the work around?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35534479/angularjs-1-5-component-does-not-support-watchers-what-is-the-work-around/35535336#35535336)

Comment: @zeroflagL  use `$watch` to biding the variable ui.shake (who was boolean) . ` $timeout` for wait the and of css animation Angular is faster than html

Comment: Angular 1.5 offers `$onChanges`, which is preferable to `$watch`. Another important point is the reason of change. If e.g. the value is changed by clicking on a button you can listen to that event. As for  `$timeout`: You can take a look into `$animate` that can call functions when the animation ends. Anyway, if you want to keep things as they are you need to replace `function(){ this.ui.shake = false;` with an arrow function, because `this` is not the controller here.

Comment: how `$onChnage`work in controller ? un prefer use `$watch`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are directly calling function instead of passing function reference in 2nd parameter.

```
this.$scope.$watch('ui.shake',this.resetUiCheck.bind(this));
```

OR

```
this.$scope.$watch('ui.shake', (newValue, oldValue) => 
   this.resetUiCheck( newValue, oldValue)
);
```

---

you can also write it in a very simple form

```
this.$scope.$watch('ui.shake', this.resetUiCheck);
```

But then you have to write underlying function in Arrow function format

```
resetUiCheck = (newValue, oldValue) => 
   this.resetUiCheck( newValue, oldValue)
);
```

Answer (score 2):

It should be:

```
this.$scope.$watch('ui.shake', this.resetUiCheck)
```

Answer (score 1):

First, never use $watch in controllers. Second, you don't need $watch.

```
$scope.ui.shake = true;
$timeout(function(){
    $scope.ui.shake = false;
}, 1000);
```