# Angular 1.5: invoke method in deep child directive from parent directive

Tags: angularjs

I have several nested directives. I now need to invoke a function in deep child.

```
<parent-directive>
    <child-directive>
        <deep-child-directive></deep-child-directive>
    </child-directive>
</parent-directive>
```

I want call method in deep-child-directive controller from parent-directive controller. 
Is there any way except $broadcast to do this?

my function:

```
$scope.refreshProductSearch = function() {
    var isRefresh = true;
    if( $rootScope.urlOption.query  ) {
        var selected = $rootScope.urlOption.query;
        if( $rootScope.urlOption.query) {
            var urlOption = util.jsonUrlParser(selected);
            isRefresh = urlOption.query.searchs ? false : true;
        }
    }
    if( isRefresh ) {
        $scope.clearValues();
    }
    $scope.$emit("removeAdvanceSearch");
};
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJs 1.5 - Component does not support Watchers, what is the work around?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35534479/angularjs-1-5-component-does-not-support-watchers-what-is-the-work-around).  See the demo of [**Use RxJS in a Service**](https://plnkr.co/edit/Y2hQkAC74JeY9WO1OxpV?p=preview)

Comment: Hi George, thanks for your response, I edit my post and add that function. Function use $scope and $rootscope, can I change that to service method?