# How to update child components from the updated list of parents

Tags: angularjs, angular-components

I'm new to Angular and currently using version 1.6.

I'm implementing the component style of Angular. I just want to ask what's the best way to communicate from parent to child components? I know there is an existing question but I have a specific scenario (I'm not sure if it's unique or not).

Here is the scenario:

Modal -> create new todo -> Parent ( update the object ) -> personal todo ( update the list )

1. I have a modal for creating todo.
2. Then after creating new todo pass the value on the parent to update the object of todo.
3. And when I updated the parent list of todo pass to the personal todo components to update the list on the view.

```
  angular.module('tab')
    .controller('TabController', TabController);

  function TabController() {
    let vm = this;
    let updatedTodoObject = {};

    vm.$onInit = function () {
      vm.personalTodo = vm.todo.own_todo;
      vm.externalTodo = vm.todo.external_todo;
    }

    vm.$onChanges = function (changes) {
      console.log('I\'m triggered');
    }

    vm.updateTodoList  = updateTodoList;

   function updateTodoList( result ) {
    updatedTodoObject = angular.copy(vm.todo);
    updatedProjectObject.user_todos.push(result)
    if( vm.todo !== updatedTodoObject) {
     vm.todo = updatedTodoObject;
    } else {
     console.log("Still in reference");
    }
   }

    vm.getUpdatedTodotList = function( ) {
      return vm.todo;
    }
  }
```

```
angular.module('...')
    .component('...', {
      bindings: {
        onResultTodoUpdated: '&'
      },
      controllerAs: 'todo',
      controller: ['TodoService', '$log', '$state', function(TodoService, $log, $state) {
        let vm = this;
        let todo = {};

        vm.newTodoModal = function() {
          TodoService.newTodoModal()
            .then(function (TodoName) {
              TodoService.createTodo(TodoName)
                .then(function(response) {
                  if( response.status === 201 ) {

                    todo = {
                      ...
                      ...
                    }

                    vm.onResultTodoUpdated( { result: todo } );
                  }
                })
                .catch(function(error) {
                  console.log(error);
                });
```

```
  angular.module('...')
    .component('...', {
      bindings: {
        todos: "<"
      },
      controllerAs: 'personal',
      controller: function(){
        let vm = this;
        vm.isShowTodoArchived = false;

        vm.$onInit = function () {
          getWatchedTodo();
        }

        function getWatchedTodo () {
         vm.todos = vm.todos;
         vm.todosSize = vm.todos.length;
        }
```

My question again is how I can pass the updated data after I create to the child component which is in charge of displaying the todo list?

**UPDATED**

```
<div class="tab-pane active" id="todosTab">
  <nv-new-todo on-result-todo-updated="todo.updateTodoList(result)"></nv-new-project>

  <div class="my-todos">
    <nv-personal-todo todos="todo.personalTodo" ></nv-personal-todo>
    <nv-external-todo todos="todo.externalTodo"></nv-external-todo>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. **Use as little code as possible that still produces the same problem.** See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: If the `TabController` is instantiated with the `ng-controller` directive, the `$onChanges` hook will never fire because the `ng-controller` directive doesn't bind anything.

Comment: The question defines two components with the name `'...'`. Which is `nvPersonalTodo`? And which is `nvExternalTodo`?

Answer (score 11):

### How to update child components with changes from parents

Use [one-way bindings `<`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-scope-)

> - `<` or `<attr` - set up a one-way (one-directional) binding between a local scope property and an expression passed via the attribute `attr`. The expression is evaluated in the context of the parent scope. If no attr name is specified then the attribute name is assumed to be the same as the local name. You can also make the binding optional by adding `?`: `<?` or `<?attr`.
>
> For example, given `<my-component my-attr="parentModel">` and directive definition of `scope: { localModel:'<myAttr' }`, then the isolated scope property `localModel` will reflect the value of `parentModel` on the parent scope. Any changes to `parentModel` will be reflected in `localModel`, but changes in `localModel` will not reflect in `parentModel`.
>
> — [AngularJS Comprehensive Directive API Reference - scope](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-scope-)

And the `$onChanges` life-cycle hook:

> - `$onChanges(changesObj)` - Called whenever one-way bindings are updated. The `changesObj` is a hash whose keys are the names of the bound properties that have changed, and the values are an object of the form `{ currentValue, previousValue, isFirstChange() }`. Use this hook to trigger updates within a component.
>
> — [AngularJS Developer Guide - Components](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component)

---

## With object **content** — Use the `$doCheck` Life-cycle Hook

When binding an object or array **reference**, the `$onChanges` hook only executes when the **value** of the reference changes. To check for changes to the **contents** of the object or array, use the `$doCheck` life-cycle hook:

```
app.component('nvPersonalTodo', {
  bindings: {
    todos: "<"
  },
  controller: function(){
    var vm = this;
    this.$doCheck = function () {
      var oldTodos;
      if (!angular.equals(oldTodos, vm.todos)) {
        oldTodos = angular.copy(vm.todos);
        console.log("new content");          
        //more code here
      };
    }
})
```

From the Docs:

> The controller can provide the following methods that act as life-cycle hooks:
>
> - `$doCheck()` - Called on each turn of the digest cycle. Provides an opportunity to detect and act on changes. Any actions that you wish to take in response to the changes that you detect must be invoked from this hook; implementing this has no effect on when `$onChanges` is called. For example, this hook could be useful if you wish to perform a **deep equality check**, or to check a Date object, changes to which would not be detected by Angular's change detector and **thus not trigger `$onChanges`.** This hook is invoked with no arguments; if detecting changes, you must **store the previous value(s) for comparison** to the current values.
>
> — [AngularJS Comprehensive Directive API Reference -- Life-cycle hooks](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#life-cycle-hooks)

For more information,

- [AngularJS angular.equals API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.equals)
- [AngularJs 1.5 - Component does not support Watchers, what is the work around?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35535336/5535245)

---

## Simple DEMO

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.component("parentComponent", {
    template: `
        <fieldset>
            Inside parent component<br>
            parentData={{$ctrl.parentData}}
            <child-component in-data="$ctrl.parentData"></child-component>
        </fieldset>
    `,
    controller: function () {
        this.$onInit = () => {
            this.parentData = 'test'
        };
    },
})
.component("childComponent",{
    bindings: {
        inData: '<',
    },
    template: `
        <fieldset>Inside child component<br>
            inData={{$ctrl.inData}}
        </fieldset>
    `,
})
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
<body ng-app="app">
    <parent-component>
    </parent-component>
<body>
```

For more information, see

- [AngularJS Developer Guide - Component-based application architecture](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component#component-based-application-architecture)
- [AngularJS Comprehensive API Reference - scope](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-scope-)

Comment: Honestly, I already did that but when I update the parent value the $onChanges, it didn't trigger to propagate the value to other child component. Any idea?

Comment: if you use objects or arrays you really have to watch out!
see this: https://blog.kwintenp.com/the-onchanges-lifecycle-hook/

Comment: @dom Thank-you for that info. I updated the answer to show how to do a deep equality check with `$doCheck` and [angular.equals](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.equals).