# Alternative to $scope.watch in angular 1.5 x

Tags: angularjs

currently I am using watch in angular Js ,but now we have upgraded to angular 1.5x and I don't want to use watch instead I am looking for some thing thing alternative to $scope.watch

I am using a global value defined in the App and I need some alternative to watch which is like a method to be called up when the value of the value is changed any where in the application.

Comment: you need to provide some code; however, even if you do, I'm not sure you'll like the responses, since you are describing the **exact purpose** of `$scope.$watch`, and not providing any reason why you don't want to use it.  I suspect that in order to eliminate `$scope.$watch`, you'll have to re-design the entire architecture of your app.

Comment: I don't want to use $scope as its angular 1.5 x and want to get rid of $scope completely

Comment: that sounds like a complete architecture change, which couldn't possibly be attempted with the information you provided here so far.  As a side note, the whole idea that "`$scope` is bad, I don't want to use it" is ridiculous.  Using scope **improperly** is a *common* issue, but it doesn't make `$scope` toxic.

Comment: @dilbar505 is on the way to release AngularJS 5. Be sensible. Its like you want to find an alternative for air and water.

Comment: Tend to agree with @Claies as you describe the purpose of $scope.$watch, why try to change that? Give an explanation as to why rather than 'I don't want to use watch', otherwise this is a question not worth answering.

Comment: Also, don't pick and choose from best practices.  Don't just decide "using `$scope` is bad, but having a global value is ok...."

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJs 1.5 - Component does not support Watchers, what is the work around?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35534479/angularjs-1-5-component-does-not-support-watchers-what-is-the-work-around)

Answer (score 0):

There are basically 2 way of doeing without $watch...

1st) explicitly call the function For exemple if your variable is binded to a n input use ng-change to call the function you need.

2nd) use property setters. For exemple if you want to bind property p of your scope you can use this code in your controller:

```
var _p = 38;
Object.defineProperty(
    $scope, 
    "p", 
    {
        get : function(){ return _p; },
        set : function(val){ 
            _p = val;
            callSomeFunction(); // Do what you have been doing with $watch
        },
     );
```

But as already said in comments $scope.$watch is not the "evil thing" to avoid

Comment: Not evil. Just deprecated. As it's explained in [dupe question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35534479/angularjs-1-5-component-does-not-support-watchers-what-is-the-work-around). $scope.$apply does not have alternatives and still should be used. $scope.$watch has them.