# angular 1.5: watch doesn't call when i toggle the ui

Tags: angularjs, watch

I my template i have:

```
    <md-checkbox ng-model="$ctrl.isAdOps" aria-label="isAdOps">
        isAdOps {{ $ctrl.isAdOps }}
    </md-checkbox>
```

In my component:

```
(function (app) {
    app.component('homeComponent', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/home-partial.html',
        bindings: {
            isAdOps: '='
        },
        controller: ['$scope', '$state', function ($scope, $state) {

            var self = this;

            $scope.$watch(
                self.isAdOps,
                function (isAdOps) {
                    $scope.$broadcast('isAdOpsToggled', isAdOps);
                }
            );
        }]
    });

})(myApp);
```

why doesn't the watch called when i toggle the md-checkbox?

Comment: `$watch('isAdOps',` $watch first param should either take function/string.

Comment: can you add as an answer? so i can mark it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular `$watch` first parameter should of type string/function

> string: Evaluated as expression
>
> function(scope): called with current scope as a parameter.

replace `self.isAdOps` with `'isAdOps'` in $watch or alternativly use a function syntax with $scope.

Answer (score 0):

You are better off using the [`ng-change`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange) directive:

```
<md-checkbox ng-model="$ctrl.isAdOps"
             ng-change="$ctrl.isAdOpsChanged($ctrl.isAdOps)"
             aria-label="isAdOps>
    isAdOps {{ $ctrl.isAdOps }}
</md-checkbox>
```

It avoids using `$scope` and adding a watcher.

For more information, see [Writing Components without Watchers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35534479/angularjs-1-5-component-does-not-support-watchers-what-is-the-work-around/35535336#35535336).

See also, [AngularJS Developer Guide - Component-based application architecture](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component#component-based-application-architecture).

Components should follow a few simple conventions:

- Inputs should be using `<` and `@` bindings. The `<` symbol denotes [one-way bindings](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-scope-) which are available since 1.5. The difference to `=` is that the bound properties in the component scope are not watched, which means if you assign a new value to the property in the component scope, it will not update the parent scope. Note however, that both parent and component scope reference the same object, so if you are changing object properties or array elements in the component, the parent will still reflect that change. The general rule should therefore be to never change an object or array property in the component scope. `@` bindings can be used when the input is a string, especially when the value of the binding doesn't change.
- Outputs are realized with `&` bindings, which function as callbacks to component events.

This will make the migration to Angular 2+ easier.