# Access value of a variable of child directive in parent directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-components, isolate-scope

How to access a variable of child directive in parent directive?
I have a parent directive like:

```
<parent-directive>
  <child-directive></child-directive>
</parent-directive>
```

child directive contains an object "states.visible"
I want to access that in parent directive.

Comment: I have been asked to use isolated scope ? I read about it but can only understand flow from parent to child not child to parent. I am working with Angular js

Comment: Flow from child to parent is done with events using  expression (method) binding defined with the `&` symbol. Child variables are encapsulated. Parent classes provide variables and methods (functions) to a child. Child classes react to variable changes and communicate events to the parent using the methods (functions) provided by the parent.

Comment: Questions asking for **homework** help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the AngularJs way of doing this would be accomplished with implementing an output in the child directive. Every time the "states" object changes the child calls the output function and the parent can do whatever it wants with it.

**AngularJS v1.5+ Method:**

**HTML**

```
<parent-directive>
  <child-directive on-state-change="$ctrl.stateChange($stateChangeObj)"></child-directive>
</parent-directive>
```

**Child Controller**

```
    $scope.$watch('$ctrl.state', function(n, old){
        ctrl.onStateChange({$stateChangeObj: n});
    })
```

**Parent Controller**

```
ctrl.stateChange = function(state){
    // do something
}
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component#component-based-application-architecture

> Note: Component based architecture was introduced in AngularJS v1.5.

---

**Prior to AngularJS v1.5 Method:**

this should technically work the same with a two way bound function. except the html would look like this

```
on-state-change="$ctrl.stateChange"
```

instead of

```
on-state-change="$ctrl.stateChange($stateChangeObj)"
```

. then in the child it would be

```
ctrl.onStateChange(n);
```

instead of

```
 ctrl.onStateChange({stateChangeObj: n});
```

Comment: Ah thank you !...Yes it is somewhat similar to what I am trying to do. I will give it a try and will post back if it worked

Comment: if you have never worked with an output, just letting you know that the stateChangeObj defined in the html is supposed to be the key in the object you pass to the output.

Comment: I cannot do it this way. I have to pass a variable using "=" .

Comment: that is two way bound variable. if you are using < angularjs 1.5 outputs are not yet available.

Comment: Can you please help me out with that ?

Comment: this should technically work the same with a two way bound function. except the html would look like this on-state-change="$ctrl.stateChange" instead of on-state-change="$ctrl.stateChange(stateChangeObj)". then in the child it would be ctrl.onStateChange(n); instead of ctrl.onStateChange({stateChangeObj: n});

Comment: In component based architecture, components avoid use of `$scope` and `$watch` as they don't upgrade to Angular 2+ well. See [Writing Components without Watchers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35535336/5535245)

Comment: The standard convention is to prefix arguments local to the child scope with a `$` sign. Use `$event` to denote a change object.