# option select within div with ng-repeat does not change ng-model

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-options

My ngModel myOpt2 does not change when selected, myOpt if it works.
Any reason why it does not change?

Mi ngModel myOpt2 no cambia al ser seleccionado, myOpt si functiona.
Alguna razon por la que no cambia?

```js
var app = angular.module('App_Alta', []);

app.controller('Ctrl_Categorias', function ($scope, $http) {

    $scope.lstCatalogos = [{ sNombre: "Vehículos", iID: 1, iIdPadre: 0, bUltimo: false }]
    $scope.lstSubCategorias = []


    $scope.$watch("myOpt", function (newval, oldval) {
        if (newval == undefined || newval.iID == 0) {
            return false;
        }
        $scope.lstSubCategorias[0] = [{ sNombre: "Autos", iID: 17, iIdPadre: 1, bUltimo: true }]
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class="example-wrap" ng-app="App_Alta" ng-controller="Ctrl_Categorias" id="AppAngular1">
  <div>
      <header Class="example-title">
          Seleccione una categoria
      </header>
      <div class="example">
          <select class="form-control" 
                  ng-model="myOpt" 
                  selectpicker="{ noneSelectedText: 'Seleccione una opción' }"
                  select-model="lstCatalogos"
                  ng-options="x.sNombre for x in lstCatalogos"></select>
      </div>
      <div class="example" ng-repeat="l in lstSubCategorias">
          <select class="form-control"
                  ng-model="myOpt2" 
                  selectpicker="{ noneSelectedText: 'Seleccione una opción' }"
                  select-model="lstSubCategorias"
                  ng-options="x.sNombre for x in l"></select>
      </div>
  </div>
<p>{{myOpt}}</p>
<p>{{myOpt2}}</p>
</div>
```

no cambia?

Comment: Please write in English.

Comment: I am voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem was caused by a simple error (variable initialization). This question was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking whether **myOpt** has actually changed, before setting **myOpt2**

```
$scope.$watch("myOpt", function (newval, oldval) {
  if(newval !== oldval) {
    if (newval == undefined || newval.iID == 0) {
        return false;
    }
    // I'm assuming this is where you are trying to make myOpt2 selected based on first select
    $scope.myOpt2 = [{ sNombre: "Autos", iID: 17, iIdPadre: 1, bUltimo: true }]
  }
});
```

Comment: No problem, glad I could help you out

Answer (score 0):

The code can be simplified by using the [`ng-change` directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange) instead if a watcher:

```js
var app = angular.module('App_Alta', []);

app.controller('Ctrl_Categorias', function ($scope, $http) {

    $scope.lstCatalogos = [{ sNombre: "Vehículos", iID: 1, iIdPadre: 0, bUltimo: false }]
    $scope.lstSubCategorias = [];
    $scope.myOpt2 = [];

    //$scope.$watch("myOpt", function (newval, oldval) {
    $scope.myOptChange = (function(newval) { 
        if (newval == undefined || newval.iID == 0) {
            return false;
        }
        $scope.lstSubCategorias[0] = [{ sNombre: "Autos", iID: 17, iIdPadre: 1, bUltimo: true }]
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class="example-wrap" ng-app="App_Alta" ng-controller="Ctrl_Categorias" id="AppAngular1">
  <div>
      <header Class="example-title">
          Seleccione una categoria
      </header>
      <div class="example">
          <!-- USE ng-change directive -->
          <select class="form-control"
                  ng-model="myOpt"
                  ng-change="myOptChange(myOpt)"
                  ng-options="x.sNombre for x in lstCatalogos">
          </select>
      </div>
      <div class="example" ng-repeat="l in lstSubCategorias">
          <select class="form-control"
                  ng-model="myOpt2[$index]"
                  ng-options="x.sNombre for x in l">
          </select>
      </div>
  </div>
<p>{{myOpt}}</p>
<p>{{myOpt2[0]}}</p>
</div>
```

Using the `ng-change` directive enhances performance as the function is invoked only when the selection changes instead of dirty checking on every digest cycle. Also it makes future migration to Angular 2+ easier as Angular 2+ has no `$scope.$watch` method.

For more information, see

- [AngularJS ng-change Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange)
- [Writing Components without Watchers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35535336/5535245)

Comment: You saved my life, I clung to the method and it did not let me move forward. Thank you very much.