# Directive's $rootScope.$on event listener remanent issue

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, broadcast, rootscope

I have a directive that contains in his controller a watcher like:

```
$rootScope.$on('broad1', (event, args) => {
            doSomething()
});
```

Then, I reload (with $state.go) a part of my page that contains my directive. And unfortunately, even if my directive is reinit and of course, not duplicated, a new watcher is created and added in my rootscope. ( I already know that when watcher are attached to rootscope, isn't destroyed whereas the directive is removed from DOM)

So, when I broadcast 'broad1' the watchers are executed n times (corresponding to n previous reloads). WHY?

Comment: use `$scope.$on()` not `$rootScope.on()`

Comment: $scope is specific to a directive, $rootScope is global to your whole application. When a directive is removed, $scope.$destroy is called and removes the $watch attached to that $scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the AngularJS event bus in directives, events **listeners** should be placed on **local scope**. Events should be **broadcast from `$rootScope`**:

```
app.directive("myDirective", function() {
    return {
        link: postLink,
    };
    function postLink(scope,elem,attrs) {
        scope.$on('broad1', (event, args) => {
            doSomething()
        });
        scope.broadcast = function(data) {
            scope.$root.$broadcast("broad1", data);
        };
    };
})
```

When the scope is destroyed the event listener will automatically be removed.

For more information, see

- [AngularJS $rootScope/$scope Type API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$on)
- [AngularJS Developer Guide - Scope Event Propagation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope#scope-events-propagation)

---

## Update

Keep in mind the the AngularJS event bus is inefficient and obsolete. Whenever possible use more direct ways to communicate events to their recipients.

From the Docs:

> ### Only use .$broadcast() and .$on() for atomic events
>
> Events that are relevant globally across the entire app (such as a user authenticating or the app closing). If you want events specific to modules, services or widgets you should consider Services, Directive Controllers, or 3rd Party Libs
>
> - Injecting services and calling methods directly is also useful for direct communication
> - Directives are able to directly communicate with each other through directive-controllers
>
> — [AngularJS Wiki - Best Practices](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Dev-Guide%3A-Best-Practices)

See also,

- [AngularJS Developer Guide - Component-based application architecture](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component#component-based-application-architecture)
- [AngularJS 1.5+ Components do not support Watchers, what is the work around?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35535336/5535245)

Comment: If you don't use $broadcast and that you want to edit something stored in the scope of parent directives, angularjs won't be able to detect it unless you explicitely call $scope.$apply on the specific directive. $on and $broadcast are working even if this is not the perfect way to handle it, but it's the way to do it in angularjs 1.X.

Comment: To communicate events from child directive to parent controller, there are several alternatives to the scope event bus that are more efficient. To make migration to Angular 2+ easier, the AngularJS team introduced components. For more information, see [AngularJS Developer Guide - Component-based application architecture](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component#component-based-application-architecture). See also [AngularJS 1.5+ Components do not support Watchers, what is the work around?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35535336/5535245).

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your reactivity and insight, I've fixed it by using the $scope.on[...] and $rootscope.broadcast[...].
In other hand the "service way" was a good one too.

Have a nice day.