# upgrading angularJS service that use $scope.$apply to angular 8

Tags: angularjs, angular

i am in the porting of some AngularJS services to Angular 8.
Some services use `$scope`. For Example one service use `$sScope.$apply` in firing events.
What can be the better method for porting these service in Angular 8 ?

I can't show any code, but there is some one can point me in the right direction suggesting articles or tutorial for doing this porting.

I have already read simple tutorials, i need some specific examples for doing porting of such things.

Thanks in advance.
Giuseppe.

Comment: Read [AngularJS 1.5+ Components do not support Watchers, what is the work around?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35534479/angularjs-1-5-components-do-not-support-watchers-what-is-the-work-around). The techniques for avoiding watchers apply to writing components that are upgradeable to Angular 2+ or other frameworks.

Answer (score 1):

**Angular** does the change detection by itself and you do not have to manually trigger the change detection unlike `$scope.apply` in `Angular JS`.

So in your case, you could ignore `$scope.apply`, because that is taken care by **Angular**

From the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/upgrade#change-detection)

> The scope.$apply() is how AngularJS detects changes and updates data
>   bindings. After every event that occurs, scope.$apply() gets called.
>   This is done either automatically by the framework, or manually by
>   you.
>
> In Angular things are different. While change detection still occurs
>   after every event, no one needs to call scope.$apply() for that to
>   happen. This is because all Angular code runs inside something called
>   the Angular zone. Angular always knows when the code finishes, so it
>   also knows when it should kick off change detection. The code itself
>   doesn't have to call scope.$apply() or anything like it.

Comment: You can still create cases pretty easily where you need to manually run change detection an angular. It generally means you’re doing things wrong, but if you’re porting from angularjs, you probably were doing things the right way then which are now “wrong”