# call a function after directive is loaded

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am working on custom directive of angular 1.6

I want to call a function after my directive is loaded. Is there a way to achieve this?

I tried link function, but it seems the link function is executed before the directive is loading.

Any help will be appreciated.

This is my directive code

```
<pagination total-data= noOfRecords></pagination>
```

```js
app.directive("pagination", [pagination]);

function pagination() {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        templateUrl: 'template/directives/pagination.html',
        scope: {
            totalData: '=',
        },
        link: dirPaginationControlsLinkFn
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using AngularJS V1.6, consider making the directive a component:

```
app.component("pagination", {
    templateUrl: 'template/directives/pagination.html',
    bindings: {
        totalData: '<',
    },
    controller: "paginationCtrl"
})
```

And use the `$onChanges` and `$onInit` [life-cycle hooks](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#life-cycle-hooks):

```
app.controller("paginationCtrl", function() {
    this.$onChanges = function(changesObj) {
        if (changesObj.totalData) {
            console.log(changesObj.totalData.currentValue);               
            console.log(changesObj.totalData.previousValue);                 
            console.log(changesObj.totalData.isFirstChange());
        };
    };
    this.$onInit = function() {
        //Code to execute after component loaded
        //...
    });
});
```

Components are directives structured in a way that they can be automatically upgraded to Angular 2+ components. They make the migration to Angular 2+ easier.

For more information, see

- [AngularJS Developer Guide - Components](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component)
- [AngularJS 1.5+ Components do not support Watchers, what is the work around?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35534479/angularjs-1-5-components-do-not-support-watchers-what-is-the-work-around)

Answer (score 1):

You might add a watch to totalData in link function and do the stuff there.

```
scope.$watch('totalData', function () {
   if (scope.totalData && scope.totalData.length > 0) { //or whatever condition is required
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try calling your function inside `$onInit()` or inside `$postLink()` [docs might help](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component)