# Unable to access scope property set by $http.get in directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-1.6

I'm using this app.js file:

```
var myNinjaApp = angular.module('myNinjaApp', []);

myNinjaApp.directive('randomNinja', [function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      theNinjas: '=',
      title: '='
    },
    template: '<img ng-src="{{theNinjas[random].thumb}}"/>',
    controller: function($scope) {
      let length = $scope.theNinjas.length; //$scope.theNinjas is undefined
      $scope.random = Math.floor(Math.random() * length);
      console.log($scope.random);
    }
  };
}]);

myNinjaApp.controller('NinjaController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {  
    $http.get('data/ninjas.json').then(function(data){
      $scope.ninjas = data.data;
    });
}]);
```

and this index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myNinjaApp">
  <head>
    <title>TheNetNinja Angular Playlist</title>
    <link href="content/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-route/1.7.9/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app\app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="NinjaController">  
    <random-ninja the-ninjas="ninjas" title="'Random Ninja'"></random-ninja>
  </body>
</html>
```

I noticed in the directive's controller code, the `$scope.theNinjas` is undefined, but the `title` isn't.

When I debug the code, I can see the `$http.get()` call is made after the `$scope.theNinjas.length` is read.

How can I get the length of the array in the directive's controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is, `$http.get` is async,

```
$http.get('data/ninjas.json').then(function(data){
   $scope.ninjas = data.data;
});
```

Therefore, you get a response a.e. initialize `$scope.ninjas` with delay.

You can go on 2 solutions:

**[Solution 1]**

Use `ng-if` to initialize the directive when `ninjas` is not `undefined`

```
<random-ninja 
  ng-if="ninjas"
  the-ninjas="ninjas" 
  title="'Random Ninja'">
</random-ninja>
```

---

**[Solution 2]**

Use `$watch` to listen on `ninjas` change and call some `run` method when `$scope.theNinjas` has value different from `undefined`. After, stop watch by calling `unreg()`

```
let length = 0;

var unreg = $scope.$watch(function () {
    return $scope.theNinjas;
},
function (newVal, oldVal) {
   if (newVal !== undefined) {
        run(newVal);
        unreg();
    }
 });


function run(){
 length = $scope.theNinjas.length; 
  $scope.random = Math.floor(Math.random() * length);
  console.log($scope.random);
}
```

Comment: Solution 1 worked perfectly well :) Don't feel the need to even try solution 2.

Comment: @DavidKlempfnerglad to hear :)

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to use the `$onChanges` life-cycle hook:

```
myNinjaApp.directive('randomNinja', [function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      ̶t̶h̶e̶N̶i̶n̶j̶a̶s̶:̶ ̶'̶=̶'̶,̶ 
      theNinjas: '<',
      title: '<'
    },
    template: '<img ng-src="{{theNinjas[random].thumb}}"/>',
    controller: function($scope) {
      this.$onChanges = function(changesObj) {
        if (changesObj.theNinjas) {
          let length = changesObj.theNinjas.currentValue.length;
          $scope.random = Math.floor(Math.random() * length);
          console.log($scope.random);
        };
      };
    }
  };
}]);
```

This will update the component directive when the `theNinjas` binding is updated with data from the server.

**Note:** The directive needs to use one-way (`<`) binding for this approach.

From the Docs:

> ## Life-cycle hooks
>
> Directive controllers can provide the following methods that are called by AngularJS at points in the life-cycle of the directive:
>
> - `$onChanges(changesObj)` - Called whenever one-way (`<`) or interpolation (`@`) bindings are updated. The `changesObj` is a hash whose keys are the names of the bound properties that have changed, and the values are an object of the form `{ currentValue, previousValue, isFirstChange() }`. Use this hook to trigger updates within a component such as cloning the bound value to prevent accidental mutation of the outer value. Note that this will also be called when your bindings are initialized.

For more information, see

- [AngularJS Comprehensive Directive API Reference - Life Cycle Hooks](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#life-cycle-hooks)
- [AngularJS Developer Guide - Component-based Application Architecture](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component#component-based-application-architecture)
- [AngularJS 1.5+ Components do not support Watchers, what is the work around?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35534479/angularjs-1-5-components-do-not-support-watchers-what-is-the-work-around/35535336#35535336)